# Not able to see relational table while querying in linq using EF

Tags: linq, lambda, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6, composite-primary-key

I have three tables in my database which are:

1. TableA (AID, Name, Salary) - Master Table
2. TableB (BID, Address, City) - Master Table
3. TableC (AID, BID) - Mapped with composite key of TableA and TableB

Now I just simply want to retrieve records using these tables plus entity framework.

```
select cm.Name, proj.Address from TableA cm
inner join TableC pc on cm.AID = pc.AID
inner join TableB proj on pc.BID=  proj.BID
```

When I querying through my context, I am not able to see TableC. I don't know why this is happening. I tried with putting self join in Linq but it did not work.

### Edit

```
[XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
        [SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        [EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("context", "TableC", "TableA")]
        public EntityCollection<TableA> TableAs
        {
            get
            {
                return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedCollection<TableA>("context.TableC", "TableA");
            }
            set
            {
                if ((value != null))
                {
                    ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedCollection<TableA>("context.TableC", "TableA", value);
                }
            }
        }


[XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
        [SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        [EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("context", "TableC", "TableB")]
        public EntityCollection<TableB> TableBs
        {
            get
            {
                return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedCollection<TableB>("context.TableC", "TableB");
            }
            set
            {
                if ((value != null))
                {
                    ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedCollection<TableB>("context.TableC", "TableB", value);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to see the junction table.

```
var results=db.TableA
  .Include(a=>a.Addresses)
  .Select(a=>new {a.Name,a.Addresses});
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. I tried this solution but could not find a.Addresses expression while writing above lambda. I believe .Include only refers relational table name which means only table name in string format.

Comment: @Akash Try placing `using System.Data.Entity;` at the top of your file.

Comment: Tried by putting the namespace mentioned above but din't work

Comment: When you put the namespace above, when you type `.Include(a=>a.` it should then tell you what you can include.  Just find your navigation property in there.  I guessed it was going to be called Addresses based on the assumption that TableB was actually called Address, and using the defaults, EF would have called the navigation property Addresses for you. If it is actually called TableB, you can try TableBs.

Comment: Thank you Robert for quick response. I guess you are referring different namespace as i am not seeing navigation properties. FYI, even after adding above namespace, .Include method only expecting string value to be passed and not the expression. I don't know what am I missing!